# Como criar pesquisa no Laravel pegando dados do cache?

Tags: php, laravel-5, cache

Já que eu tenho esses dados em um arquivo não vejo porque fazer uma requisição no banco de dados.

Exemplo do meu código cacheado:

`$produtos = Cache::rememberForever('produtos', function () {
    return DB::table('produtos')
    ->get();
});
$produtos = \Cache::get('produtos');`

Exemplo do meu código que busca os dados do banco de dados:

`$produtos = Produto::where('titulo', 'like', '%'.Input::get('texto').'%')
    ->orWhere('descricao', 'like', '%'.Input::get('texto').'%')
    ->get();`

Tentei fazer algo parecido com isso:

`$produtos = \Cache::get('produtos')->where('titulo', 'like', '%'.Input::get('texto').'%');`

mas sem sucesso, alguem teria uma sugestão de como proceder, desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda :).

Answer (score 1):

Fazendo uma leve pesquisa eu encontrei uma solução que pode te servir.

Em vez de fazer uma busca no seu cache, você pode armazenar a busca usando sua url como key na primeira vez que você pedir por ela, e na segunda vez que ele fizer a mesma busca, você retorna os dados ao fazer uma busca pela url no Cache.

```
// Primeiro ele pega o url da requisição
$url = request()->url();

// Depois os parametros de query da requisição
$queryParams = request()->query();

// Ordena os parametros
ksort($queryParams);

// E torna em string os parametros ordenados
$queryString = http_build_query($queryParams);

// Monta o url completo junto com os parametros
$fullUrl = "{$url}?{$queryString}";

// Encripta o url em sha1 para facilitar o armazenamento
$rememberKey = sha1($fullUrl);

// Em seguida faz Cache e depois retorna o valor armazenado.
return Cache::rememberForever($rememberKey, function () use ($data) {
    return $data;
});
```

No post original, ele armazenava resultados de uma paginação.
Como você quer busca o titulo e a descrição, você pode montar sua rota assim:

```
Route::get('/path/{titulo?}/{descricao?}', 'Controller@index');
```

Há outras opções para você também como o [Laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scout), mas acredito que ele não cubra sua necessidade mas vale a pena dar uma olhada.

Resposta baseada neste [fonte](https://laravel-news.com/cache-query-params).

Comment: Eu já havia me deparado com este post porém e achei que não seria tão interessante porque criar um novo cache a cada consulta a sua dica de mudar minha abordagem com Laravel Scout me parece ser a solução para o meu problema, Obrigado Vinicius Lourenço :).